# Null pointer exception in UrlImage

Tags: codenameone

I've 2 images in a screen which uses URLImage. In some devices eg Huawei(MARSHMALLOW), it gives null point exception ie.

> An internal application error occurred:
>   java.lang.nullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference.

However the problem has never occured in simulator or samsung devices.

```
EncodedImage placeholder = (EncodedImage) res.getImage("home_car.png");
placeholder = (EncodedImage) placeholder.scaledEncoded((Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 3), -1);

EncodedImage logoPlaceholder = (EncodedImage) res.getImage("carLogo.jpg");

String carImagePreferences = Preferences.get(AllUrl.carImage, "");
String modelLogoPreferences = Preferences.get(AllUrl.modelLogo, "");

Label vehicleNameLabel = new Label();
if (!"".equals(modelLogoPreferences)) {
    vehicleNameLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(logoPlaceholder, modelLogoPreferences, AllUrl.baseUrlCarModel
            + Preferences.get(AllUrl.modelLogo, null), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));
} else {
    vehicleNameLabel.setIcon(logoPlaceholder);
}

Label homeCarLabel = new Label();
if (!"".equals(carImagePreferences)) {
    homeCarLabel.setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, carImagePreferences, AllUrl.baseUrlCarModel
            + Preferences.get(AllUrl.carImage, null), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));
} else {
    homeCarLabel.setIcon(placeholder);
}
```

[image]

Error Log:

03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject D/Nehhpa: [EDT] 0:2:25,856 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - create image failed for the given image data of length: 211148
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 211148
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:655)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternal(EncodedImage.java:366)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:341)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:512)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$2.adaptImage(URLImage.java:103)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:239)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:302)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:298)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.util.CallbackDispatcher.run(CallbackDispatcher.java:53)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1073)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:961)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
03-28 22:34:05.429 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject D/Nehhpa: [EDT] 0:2:25,887 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:748)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.scale(AndroidImplementation.java:1735)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:1008)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledImpl(Image.java:954)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:919)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation$33.save(AndroidImplementation.java:6617)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaledEncoded(EncodedImage.java:627)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$2.adaptImage(URLImage.java:104)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.actionPerformed(URLImage.java:239)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:302)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$4.onSucess(URLImage.java:298)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.util.CallbackDispatcher.run(CallbackDispatcher.java:53)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1073)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:961)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
03-28 22:34:05.459 22121-22135/com.bbeck.myProject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: You need to connect the device with a cable and look through the DDMS logs. If you have a pro account you can turn on crash protection and you should get an email with the stack trace. It would help in tracking that.

Comment: I didn't see the issue till now but it appeared again. The image was working before. Please have a look at the error log above.

Comment: My first guess would be that your device couldn't load the image because it ran out of memory.

Comment: The image size is 211148 bytes as mentioned in the top of the stack

Comment: the size of the encoded image data has no direct relationship to the size of the image it will create.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a server returns invalid data for an image but doesn't return a proper HTTP error code. So if your server returned a corrupt image e.g. an HTML page with a 200 based response code (or after a 30x response) then we think it's the image and try to download/load it.

We'll try to add better handling for this case so it will just try to download again in the future. But that's not ideal so you need to track this image.

I suggest using the network manager to see what went wrong in the request/response.

Comment: this the url of the image. http://websamplesnow.com/62/nehhpa/appadmin/assets/location/180315100231kathmandu1.jpeg 
It works in simulator. The issue appeared in android devices only. However previously it works in the devices as well.

Comment: Is it possible the site returns a different result for a device user agent? Maybe the mime type is problematic?

Comment: Since I use UrlImage, it saves the image in a file name and everytime it is loaded, it uses same cached image, hence it always shows the error. I uninstalled and then install it again & it starts working. How can I solve it? I don't think its a mime type issue. There are couple of images in the json and all work well but some. If theres a html response code error, all the images should have corrupted as well, shouldn't they?

Comment: If the problem is a that a corrupt image has been cached, you should be able to prevent the caching by adding ?xxx to the url.  Its better to embed images in the application than to download them if they are not changeable.

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL with an error? What's the response code from the server? If we get anything other than 2xx or 3xx we don't save the data.